# Filling text in Html <marquee> tag by text file

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to update marquee tag with a external text file in following manner:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".marque").load("update/update.txt"); 
}

<center><p style="color:  rgb(0, 153, 255);font-size: 22px;">Updates</p></center>
<marquee class="marque" direction="up" behavior="scroll" scrollAmount="2">
</marquee>
```

Although its working in IE but not in Google . Can anybody have idea why is it so?

Comment: Look in the F12 error console

Comment: @AlexK I tried with F12 I find no errors. I do not know Y google is not allowing this feature.

Comment: Marquee? What year is it???

Comment: @JohnKiller: *Someone* had to say it. ;-)

Comment: @Rishav: I think you need to check the console again. Assuming the syntax error in your question isn't present in your real code, I'm pretty sure if you look on the Console tab in dev tools you'll see `XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///yourpathhere/update/update.txt. Received an invalid response. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.`

Answer (score 1):

> Although its working in IE but not in Google...

By this I'm guessing you mean Google Chrome. That tells me you're loading your page from the file system, not a web server; e.g., the URL starts with `file://`. No form of ajax works in Chrome with locally-loaded pages. If you load it from a web server, it'll work.

Comment: Yes T.J  you guessed rite Google Chrome. I got it thanks for your help.

Comment: T.J Could to help me in getting a requirement done. The requirement is  I need to update  scrolling up text in a div tag from external file(demo.text for example), using java-script or jquery

Comment: @Rishav: You can, just not if you're loading the page through a `file://` URL.